# How to split Examples in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

Suppose i have a cucumber scenario like:

```
Scenario Outline: do something
    Given do something with "<data1>"
    AND done some process on "<data2>"
    When again done some experiment on "<data3>"
    Then checking "<result>"

    Examples:
     | data1 | data2 | data3 |result  |
     | value1| value2| value3| result1|
```

This scenario is completely fine, but imagine a this scenario with 5 more step with new data. That looks very annoying. Is there any way i can spit this examples table into column. If column spit is not possible then any other suggestion.

Comment: 'but imagine'  I'm having trouble understanding what you want me to imagine.. I could go a lot of directions with "5 more steps with new data".  Also unsure what 'split this examples table into column' (given it already has columns) is supposed to mean.  Perhaps if you actually were to provide the specific example of what you are trying to do that would help us understand your objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row of examples should have a reason behind them. If two rows have the same reason behind them, then you are just wasting runtime repeating yourself.

Lets take a simple example

```
Scenario Outline
  When I register as <account> with <passsword>
  Then I should be <result>

Examples
| account | password  | result       |
| free    | too_short | unregistered |
| taken   | ok        | unregistered |
...
```

You can easily replace this complex scenario with two much simpler ones

```
Scenario: register with too short a password
  When I register with too short a password
  Then I should be told I need a longer password

Scenario: register with existing account
  When I register with an existing account
  Then I should be told the account is taken
```

There are several reasons to prefer doing things in this way

1. Each scenario is simpler to read
2. Each scenario tells you WHAT the behaviour is and WHY its important (with the examples you have to infer that from the data)
3. Each step definition is much simpler to implement
4. By making concrete the specifics of the example, you invite writing more scenarios around a particular subject.

You can apply this pattern to every Scenario Outline, and doing so will

- fix your problem with to many examples
- help you write better scenarios and code. Finding out the reason behind each example helps you write better code.

Comment: There are times I like this approach, and times I like using groups of examples.   You need to mostly go by feel and consider what makes the feature file the easiest for humans to follow  If you would end up with only a single example per group, I like just making a stand alone scenario as above.  If after dividing you still have multiple rows of examples, then likely using the scenario outline often still makes sense

Comment: I never like groups of examples, or examples in general. I always think an example is unfinished; because you haven't extracted the reasoning behind the example and haven't found a name. Examples are fine when people are first getting together in conversation, but once you have implemented your scenarios you now have code and un-named code is just to in-precise IMO.

Comment: how is it un-named if you name the example groups as in my answer below?

Comment: the group is named, the individual examples aren't. I'm saying that each example has a related piece of behaviour that we can extract, name and explore further. Often this exploration leads to a single example becoming a whole features with many scenarios. By keeping the examples in tables and not naming each one you are preventing the exploration of that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any other solution. The purpose of the examples is especially to have several lines:

```
Examples:
 | data1 | data2 | data3 |result  |
 | value1| value2| value3| result1|
 | value11| value12| value13| result2|
 | value21| value22| value23| result3|
```

if you do not have several lines, you can put the data directly in your scenario (not `Scenario Outline`):

```
Scenario : do something
    Given do something with "value1"
    AND done some process on "value2"
    When again done some experiment on "value3"
    Then checking "result1"
```

Comment: i don't want to add row . i want add new column and then split it with column like.
Examples:
| data1 | data2 |
Examples:
| data3 | result  |

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding what you want to do, or what you mean by 'column split', so not sure if this answers your question or not.

You can split your examples up into different groups where the examples have a common theme, you can even tag those groups

```
   @golden_path
 Examples: valid values
| data1  | data2  | data3  | result  |
| value1 | value2 | value3 | result1 |
| bar    | foo    | fizz   | buzz    |

   @low_boundary @negative_test
 Examples: low boundaries
| data1  | data2  | data3  | result  |
| 0      | smag   | cruft  | resultx |
| bar    | 0      | fizz   | resulty |
```

That allows you to better understand the purpose of given groups of example values, and even run subsets of scenario outlines based on using tags.

Key thing to remember is that the header row has to be there for each set of examples (I always try to just split them up and leave that out, resulting in an error)